# How can I format a negative currency using a Thymeleaf attribute processor?

Tags: thymeleaf

I need to display negative currency-formatted values in a table, using Thymeleaf.  Currently, I'm using `#numbers.formatDecimal` to achieve this, as follows:

```
<td th:text="${'$' + #numbers.formatDecimal(value, 1, 'DEFAULT', 2, 'DEFAULT)}" />
```

For a `value` greater than zero, this works fine:

```
<td>$34.50</td>
```

But for a negative `value`, I get:

```
<td>$-12.75</td>
```

This isn't correct - I need the currency symbol to be moved to the right of the minus sign.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'd just use a [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to apply the formatting exactly as you need:

```
<td th:text="${new java.text.DecimalFormat('$#,##0.00;$-#,##0.00').format(value)}" />
```

Comment: have to admit, this solution looks way more clean than mine, +1

Answer (score 0):

Since inserting the dollar sign in the position you want is not possible with the thymeleaf postprocessors api, you need to do some processing on your own:

You use `th:if` (or `th:unless`) to deal with the 2 possible cases, positive or negative value

In the case of a positive `value` you can use your code.

In the case of a negative `value`, you can use `th:with` to create a variable with the positive value of `value`, and then modify the `th:text` to put the minus sign before the dollar and use the new variable you've created.

```
<td th:if="${value >= 0}"
    th:text="${'$' + #numbers.formatDecimal(value, 1, 'DEFAULT', 2, 'DEFAULT)}" />
<td th:if="${value < 0}"
    th:with="inverted=${-value}"
    th:text="${'-$' + #numbers.formatDecimal(inverted, 1, 'DEFAULT', 2, 'DEFAULT)}" />
```

After it has been processed, only one of the `<td />` will be printed